# Angular 2 ES5 QueryList NoAnnotationError

Tags: angular

Based off of the limited documentation for the [QueryList interface](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/IQueryList-interface.html), I attempted to try making a component with it:

```
var Pane = ng.Component({
    selector: 'pane',
    properties: ['heading'],
  })
  .View({
    template: `
      <h2>{{heading}}</h2>
      <content></content>`
  })
  .Class({constructor: function PaneCtor() {}});

var Tabs = ng.Component({
    selector: 'tabs',
  })
  .View({
    directives: [Pane, ng.NgFor],
    template: `
      <ul>
        <li *ng-for="#pane of panes">{{pane.heading}}</li>
      </ul>
      <content></content>`
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: [
      new ng.Query(Pane),
      function TabsCtor(panes) {
        this.panes = panes;
      }
    ]
  });
```

[Broken Demo](http://codepen.io/kaleb/pen/YXdKzO)

How do I get this to work? Is it an issue with the ES5 DSL?

Answer (score 1):

As it is shown in the documentation ([QueryFactory interface](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/annotations/QueryFactory-interface.html)), you must pass the `queryList` as the second value in the array.

```
var MyComponent = ng
  .Component({...})
  .View({...})
  .Class({
    constructor: [new ng.Query(SomeType), function(queryList) {
      ...
    }]
  })
```

So you just have to add it

```
.Class({
    constructor: [
      [new ng.Query(Pane), function(queryList) {

      }],
      function TabsCtor(panes) {
        this.panes = panes;
      }
    ]
  });
```

That simple. Here's your [pen updated](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGVqZa).

I hope it helps

Comment: In the docs, it says `var MyComponent = ng
  .Component({...})
  .View({...})
  .Class({
    constructor: [new ng.Query(SomeType), function(queryList) {
      ...
    }]
  })`, so I guess it's a bug in the docs.

Comment: It might be a mistake in the docs. The doc in general is a little bit out of date, so you could pull a request fixing issues you find to help them.

Comment: Your update still does not populate the QueryList with pane instances, though. So I'm not sure what the proper documentation fix would be right now.

Comment: Now it is working. Apparently I removed the `Pane` directive from the `App` component when I was testing your problem, so I re-added it. I updated the Pen in the answer http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGVqZa